# How to read custom data from a notification in IOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm building a small IOS application rendering a web application via WebKitView.

I need to pass an extra information in the APNS payload to handle the routing of the app. Let's say your post has a new comment.

When reading the apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html). I can see  custom data can be added.

```
{
  "aps" : {
    "alert" : "You got your emails.",
    "badge" : 9,
    "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
  },
  "url" : "https://domain.ext/post/1"
}
```

How can I access `url` from:

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

//        if let page = response.notification["url"] as? String {
//            print(url)
//        }
        completionHandler()
    }
```

Comment: And what's printed by `response.notification.request.content`?

Comment: if let page = response.notification["aps"]["url"] as? String {
           print(url)
        }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
print(userInfo["url"])
```

Answer (score 2):

like this:

```
let data = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
if let url = data["url"] as? String {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Sh_Khan answered a bit before you so I accepted his but yours is also correct.